# PHP file encoded with base64 and goto

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, decoding

I want to ask something about php file encoding.

I have a php file that has one or more functions.

See example

```
function test1($var1)
{
    goto ujOS8;
    dm5qC:
    mejc1:
    goto xvuXg;
    ujOS8:
    if (!($var1 === NULL)) {
        goto mejc1;
    }
    goto Ogrl4;
    xvuXg:
    return $var1;
    goto JZZCG;
    Ogrl4:
    $var1 = 123;
    goto dm5qC;
    JZZCG:
}
```

I don't know how has been created this function.

Any ideas of how i can turn the following function like the one above and the reverse?

```
function myfunct($var) {
    if ($var == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: _I want to ask something about php file encoding._ And what do you want to ask about encoding? And `function test1($var1)` an can be coded like the second one.

Comment: Has you can see the question is below "Any ideas of how i can turn the following function like the one above and the reverse?"
I want to know how can i turn the myfunct code like the example above.

Comment: Then go and write a script to uglfiy the code, like the trick the test1() functions does with `goto`; Do you now how goto works ?

Comment: Of course i know how to use goto. The test that i entered it's a small one. If you have a php file with 2000 or more lines of code there is no way someone will uglyfy the code one by one. There must be one way when someone can do this automatically

Answer (score -1):

```
function test1($var1)
{
    if (($var1 === NULL)) {
       $var1 = 123;
    }

    return $var1;
}
```

- `goto` is never used as your first example shows. I think someone just did make a joke.
- The `if` part makes only sense when using this as args `test1($var1=NULL)`
- *"can turn the following function like the one above and the reverse?"* Don't now what you mean here.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  OP is looking for a PHP code obfuscator.

Comment: No that is not a joke. I have a big file (about 4500 lines)  that someone created and i want to make some changes. But if all the file is created by goto is like trying to change a labyrinth inside the labyrinth. I think that the clean code of the file will about 1500-2000 lines.